# Vim not loading vimrc file when editing files on usb stick

Tags: vim, command-line-interface, windows-7-x64

First and foremost. This is my first time using stack overflow, so pardon me if I'm doing something wrong.

I'm using Vim 8.0 on windows 7.
This is were I put my vimrc file:

```
%userprofile%\vimfiles\vimrc
%userprofile%\_vimrc
```

_vimrc only contains "runtime vimrc".

When running Vim on my `%HOMEDRIVE%`, the vimrc file is loaded correctly. But when changing to another drive, let's say drive `D:`, the `$VIM\_vimrc` one gets loaded.

Here's `:scriptnames` for both cases:

When running Vim when on D:

```
  1: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc
  2: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\vimrc_example.vim
  3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\defaults.vim
  4: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\syntax.vim
  5: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\synload.vim
  6: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\syncolor.vim
  7: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\filetype.vim
  8: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\ftplugin.vim
  9: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\indent.vim
 10: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack\dist\opt\matchit\plugin\matchit.vim
 11: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\mswin.vim
 12: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\autoload\paste.vim
 13: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
 14: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\gzip.vim
 15: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\logiPat.vim
 16: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\manpager.vim
 17: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\matchparen.vim
 18: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
 19: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\rrhelper.vim
 20: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\spellfile.vim
 21: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
 22: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tohtml.vim
 23: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
 24: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
```

When running Vim when on C:

```
1: C:\Users\310188722\_vimrc
2: C:\Users\310188722\vimfiles\vimrc
3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\colors\blue.vim
4: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
5: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\gzip.vim
6: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\logiPat.vim
7: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\manpager.vim
8: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\matchparen.vim
9: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
10: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\rrhelper.vim
11: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\spellfile.vim
12: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
13: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tohtml.vim
14: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
15: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
```

Here's `vim -V` for both cases, just in case:

`D:`

```
could not source "$VIM\vimrc"
could not source "$HOME\_vimrc"
could not source "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
sourcing "$VIM\_vimrc"
line 1: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80/vimrc_example.vim"
line 18: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80/defaults.vim"
line 77: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\syntax.vim"
Searching for "syntax/synload.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\syntax/synload.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\syntax/synload.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax/synload.vim"
line 19: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\synload.vim"
Searching for "syntax/syncolor.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax/syncolor.vim"
line 21: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\syncolor.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\syncolor.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\synload.vim
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\syntax/syncolor.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\synload.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\syntax.vim
Searching for "filetype.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\filetype.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\filetype.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\filetype.vim"
line 25: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\filetype.vim"
Searching for "ftdetect/*.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\ftdetect/*.vim"
not found in 'runtimepath': "ftdetect/*.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\filetype.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\syntax.vim
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\filetype.vim"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\filetype.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\syntax.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\defaults.vim
Searching for "filetype.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\filetype.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\filetype.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\filetype.vim"
line 92: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\filetype.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\filetype.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\defaults.vim
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\filetype.vim"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\filetype.vim"
Searching for "ftplugin.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\ftplugin.vim"
line 92: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\ftplugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\ftplugin.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\defaults.vim
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "indent.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"

Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\indent.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\indent.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\indent.vim"
line 92: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\indent.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\indent.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\defaults.vim
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\indent.vim"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\indent.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80/defaults.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\vimrc_example.vim
Searching for "pack/*/opt/matchit" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\pack/*/opt/matchit"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\pack/*/opt/matchit"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack/*/opt/matchit"
line 57: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack\dist\opt\matchit\plugin\matchit.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack\dist\opt\matchit\plugin\matchit.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\vimrc_example.vim
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\pack/*/opt/matchit"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\pack/*/opt/matchit"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80/vimrc_example.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc
line 2: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80/mswin.vim"
Searching for "autoload/paste.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack\dist\opt\matchit,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\autoload/paste.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\autoload/paste.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\autoload/paste.vim"
line 47: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\autoload\paste.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\autoload\paste.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\mswin.vim
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80/mswin.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc
finished sourcing $VIM\_vimrc
Searching for "plugin/**/*.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack\dist\opt\matchit,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin/**/*.vim"
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\gzip.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\gzip.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\logiPat.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\logiPat.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\manpager.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\manpager.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\matchparen.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\matchparen.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\rrhelper.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\rrhelper.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\spellfile.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\spellfile.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tarPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tohtml.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tohtml.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\zipPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack\dist\opt\matchit\plugin/**/*.vim"
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack\dist\opt\matchit\plugin\matchit.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack\dist\opt\matchit\plugin\matchit.vim
Searching for "pack/*/start/*" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\pack/*/start/*"
not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "pack/*/start/*" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\pack/*/start/*"
not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "plugin/**/*.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack\dist\opt\matchit,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\plugin/**/*.vim"
not found in 'runtimepath': "plugin/**/*.vim"
Reading viminfo file "\Users\310188722\_viminfo" info oldfiles
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

`C:`

```
could not source "$VIM\vimrc"
sourcing "$HOME\_vimrc"
Searching for "vimrc" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\vimrc"
line 1: sourcing "\Users\310188722\vimfiles\vimrc"
Searching for "colors/blue.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\colors/blue.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\colors/blue.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\colors/blue.vim"
line 4: sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\colors\blue.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\colors\blue.vim
continuing in C:\Users\310188722\vimfiles\vimrc
finished sourcing \Users\310188722\vimfiles\vimrc
continuing in C:\Users\310188722\_vimrc
finished sourcing $HOME\_vimrc
Searching for "plugin/**/*.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin/**/*.vim"
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\gzip.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\gzip.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\logiPat.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\logiPat.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\manpager.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\manpager.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\matchparen.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\matchparen.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\rrhelper.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\rrhelper.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\spellfile.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\spellfile.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tarPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tohtml.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tohtml.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\zipPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
Searching for "pack/*/start/*" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\pack/*/start/*"
not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "pack/*/start/*" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\pack/*/start/*"
not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/start/*"
Searching for "plugin/**/*.vim" in "\Users\310188722/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after\plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "\Users\310188722/vimfiles/after\plugin/**/*.vim"
not found in 'runtimepath': "plugin/**/*.vim"
Reading viminfo file "\Users\310188722\_viminfo" info oldfiles
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Do any of you know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance :)